# Should I group related data fields and views together, or group data fields into a DataClass (as well as group views into a ViewsClass)?

Tags: java, object-oriented

For example, if I have a game which have some components, which has Player and Enemy,as well as the parent container,Game, e.g.:

**Version 1**:

```
public class Player{
    private int hp;
    private Label hpLabel();
    //some other properties
}

public class Enemy{
    private int hp;
    private Label hpLabel();
    //some other properties
}

//some other component classes

public class Game{
    Player player;
    Enemy enemy;
    //some other components
    public void changeState(int state){
        //game loop
    }
}
```

and another style which groups data fields (as well as views) into a single class:

**Version 2**

```
public class GameData{
    public int playerHp;
    public int enemyHp;
    //some other data field
}

public class GameViews{
    public Label playerHpLabel;
    public Label enemyHpLabel;
    //some other views
}

public class Game{
    public GameData gameData;
    public GameViews gameViews;
    public void changeState(int state){
        //game loop
    }
}
```

I know Version 1 is the standard way to do this, but I also found Version 2 has some advantages, eg: It lets me have a big picture about which data or state would the game has, as well as which UI components available at the screen. which version should I use?

Comment: "Version 1 is the standard way to do this" not really. You are not showing any reason for a distinction between `Player` and `Enemy`, as they have the same members (and no behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which version should I use?

Neither. Or both. Depending on how you look at it.

**Version 1**

- You're properly encapsulating the logic of `Player` and `Enemy` in their respective classes.
- Unfortunately, you're also mixing business logic (like `hp`) with presentation concerns (like `hpLabel`).

**Version 2**

- The presentation related logic is cleanly separated from the business logic.
- Unfortunately, the different entities (`Player` and `Enemy`) are now spread all over the business layer. Sooner or later, you're going to have a mess.

**Solution**

The 'correct' object oriented approach is to have a `Player` and an `Enemy` class that own their respective states and implement the appropriate business logic (like `Move()`, `Die()`, etc). However, they do not contain any view-related things, like labels.

In addition, you have a `PlayerView` and an `EnemyView` that have a reference to their respective domain objects. This is where you implement all the UI logic. The view classes don't have to mirror your domain classes - a view may reference multiple domain classes, and a domain class may be referenced by multiple views.

Your game object then holds a reference to your top-level model objects, as well as to your top-level view objects.